# Kibana query where a field is less/greater other field (ex. field1 < field2 )

Tags: kibana

I can query against a constant: `field1: < 10`

but , what about another field? Example: `field1 < field2`

Comment: 99% sure it's not possible, though I can't find a github issue about it...